# CW Complex Structure on Disk with 2 holes and boundaries identified

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I wish to put a CW complex structure on a space $X$ obtained as follows. Delete the interiors of two disjoint subdiscs in the interior of $D^2$, and then identify all three resulting boundary circles via homeomorphisms preserving
clockwise orientation of these circles.

I know how to put a CW complex structure on the space before the resulting boundaries are identified. There are 3 0-cells, 5 1-cells and 1 2-cell, see my crudely drawn picture below to see how they're identified. But I don't really know how to go from this to the actual desired space.

[image: crudely drawn image]

Comment: You may find this helpful: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262084/computing-the-homology-groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262084/computing-the-homology-groups)

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is the exercise in Hatcher's book. Consider the following CW structure: one $0$-cell $x$, three $1$-cells $a$,$b$ and $c$ and one $2$-cell $U$, whose boundary is given by $aba^{-1}b^{-1}ca^{-1}c^{-1}$.

[image]